return all instances of a string in a specific Excel column when they are grouped in a pivot table
I am trying to get the cell address of all cells in a crosstab column that contain specific text. The problem is only the first cell in the group has the string. The preceding cells in the group are blank.

I can get the cell address of the first instance but not the rest. This is what I have so far:
Public Function FindRowNumber(ByVal SheetName As String, ByVal txt As String, ByVal row As Integer) As Integer
    Dim CellValue As String = ""
    Dim Proceed As Boolean
    Try
        For x As Integer = 1 To xlWorkSheets.Count
            xlWorkSheet = CType(xlWorkSheets(x), Excel.Worksheet)
            If xlWorkSheet.Name = SheetName Then
                Proceed = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        With xlWorkSheet
            XLRange = .Range("C" & row & ":C950").Find(What:=txt)
            MsgBox(XLRange.Cells.ToString,, "ExcelModule.FindRowNumber Sub")
            For y As Integer = 1 To XLRange.Rows.Count
                'MsgBox(Range(row).value.ToString,, "ExcelModule.FindRowNumber sub")
                ' MsgBox(y)
            Next
            xlRow = XLRange.Row
        End With
    Catch
        MsgBox(Err.Number & ", " & Err.Description & " -" & txt,, "FindCellValue")
        Return 0
    End Try
End Function

